# Segmentation fault while calling globfree()

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, glob

**[using arm-hisiv300-linux-gcc to compile for Linux based Target board]**

I got segmentation fault while I called this function.

```
uint32_t dir_disp(void)
{
    uint32_t        err;
    uint32_t        i;
    size_t          cnt;
    char            *str;
    char            **p;

    glob_t          glob_results;   

    err = glob("/home/2019-11-12/H*", GLOB_MARK, 0, &glob_results);

    p = glob_results.gl_pathv;
    cnt = glob_results.gl_pathc;

    for (i=0; i<cnt; i++)
    {
        printf("[DEBUG] dir_disp: %s\n",p[i]);
    }

    globfree(&glob_results);
    return 0;
}
```

the above function is called only once from a **thread function**, the segmentation fault occurred only when there are more than ~100 items matching the pattern "`/home/2019-11-12/H*`"

Segmentation fault doesn't occur if:

- less than ~100 items matching the pattern
- or comment out the printf in for loop
- or comment out globfree()
- or call the function in another program without thread

[Edit]

Sorry but I forgot to mention the segfault occur only after printing all the items matching the pattern.

I checked the ret val of `glob()` and found it to be zero. Not changing the original question.

Comment: In the cases where it segfaults, what's in `err`? (And why isn't your code checking it?)

Comment: err is zero i checked right now.

Comment: the function: `glob()` returns an `int`, not a `uint32_t`

Comment: @user3629249 thanks for pointing that out, err should have been signed int. but in this scenario its same in both cases.

Comment: You should check the ret from glob function, because if ret is not 0, use glob_results is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Linux manpage, `glob()` is [not MT-safe](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html#ATTRIBUTES) so it is ["not safe to call in a multithreaded program"](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/attributes.7.html).

It's possibly worth noting that Posix does require `glob()` to be MT-safe, so this attribute is specific to the Gnu implementation in glibc, and might have to do with Gnu extensions such as the tilde expansion option. All the same, you should be aware of the warning.

Based on the symptoms you report, a possible issue is stack overflow, perhaps related to the use of `alloca` or VLAs in the `glob` implementation. (I didn't check the source code, though; I have no particular evidence that such features are actually used.) Default stack sizes in multithreaded code tend to be quite small, and code which works fine in a non-MT environment can easily exceed the stack size of a default thread. You could try increasing the stack size when you create the thread(s) which call `glob`.

Comment: To be specific, it's `MT-Unsafe race:utent env sig:ALRM timer locale`. Doesn't that mean it's only unsafe in those particular ways, and if your program avoids those cases, then it is fine to call in a multithreaded program?

Comment: @joseph: yes, that's what it means. And, as I said, it's possible that the issues are only triggered by certain uses of the function, although that's not documented anywhere. So it's not necessarily a reason to not use `glob` but it does indicate the need for caution. I think stack overflow is a more likely culprit.

Comment: @rici thanks mate it really was stack overflow segfault was gone once I assigned more stack in pthread.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality

Notice how the first parameter to `glob()` is written

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <glob.h>
#include <stdio.h>


uint32_t dir_disp(void)
{
    int             err;
    size_t          cnt;
    char            **p;

    glob_t          glob_results;   

    err = glob("/home/richard/*", GLOB_MARK, 0, &glob_results);

    printf( "err: %d\n", err );

    p = glob_results.gl_pathv;
    cnt = glob_results.gl_pathc;

    for (size_t i=0; i<cnt; i++)
    {
        printf("[DEBUG] dir_disp: %s\n",p[i]);
    }

    globfree(&glob_results);
    return 0;
}


int main( void )
{
    uint32_t result = dir_disp();
    printf( "result: %d\n", result );
}
```

a run of the above code results in:

```
err: 0
[DEBUG] dir_disp: /home/richard/Desktop/
[DEBUG] dir_disp: /home/richard/Documents/
[DEBUG] dir_disp: /home/richard/Downloads/
[DEBUG] dir_disp: /home/richard/Music/
[DEBUG] dir_disp: /home/richard/OpenMPI/
[DEBUG] dir_disp: /home/richard/Pictures/
[DEBUG] dir_disp: /home/richard/Public/
[DEBUG] dir_disp: /home/richard/Templates/
[DEBUG] dir_disp: /home/richard/Videos/
[DEBUG] dir_disp: /home/richard/examples.desktop
result: 0
```

there were lots of other directories, but they are not relevant to this answer

Comment: sorry mate but i did mention code was working fine if not in a thread.

Comment: well, the signature for `dir_disp()` is not valid for a thread. and the proper exit from a thread is via: `pthread_exit( NULL );`  and the function where the thread is started needs a call to `pthread_create()` to start the thread, then call `pthread_join( NULL );`  to wait for the thread to finish.  when programming the details make the difference between working and crashing.  A thread gets its' own stack.  Perhaps you need to modify the stack allocation for a thread

Comment: dir_disp() is not the threaded function but is called from a function running in thread.

Comment: Then you need to post a [mcve] so we have a complete picture of what is going on.  Then we can help you debug it.